# Shadowed terms in help

Tags: help-system

Occasionally, when I'm searching the help system for a particular topic, it will be shadowed by a different topic.

For example, if I do `:h display` I get help for something involving "GUI Resources", when I wanted help for the "display" setting (as in `set display=lastline`).

How can I find these "shadowed" topics, or list the most relevant matching topics?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Setting names are always surrounded by quotes, so use:

```
:help 'display'
```

to get the page you want.

You get some useful completions when pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, ie:

```
:help display<^D>
```

Will give you:

```
-display  :display  'display'  :syn-display  strdisplaywidth()
```

As completions :-)

Bonus tip:
If you use `:set wildmenu`, this will also work with <kbd>Tab</kbd>, and you will have some additional completion features.

Comment: Without `'wildmenu'`, you get one completion after another via Tab, or still the whole list with Ctrl-D. Suggest mentioning that.

Comment: @derobert Ah, didn't know that. I'm so used to using `Tab` :-)

Comment: For settings, `:help 'display'` is the same as `:help display?`.

Answer (score 11):

Help for **Ex commands** is always listed with the colon included:

`:help :display`

Help for **settings** is always listed with surrounding quotes, [as Carpetsmoker already described](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/441/343):

`:help 'display'`

**Specific help files** are listed by their file name:

`:help undo.txt` (cf. `:help undo`)

Help for **built-in functions** is listed with trailing parentheses:

`:help split()` (cf. `:help split`)

Documentation for Vim's **command arguments** (i.e. those passed when invoking Vim from the shell) is listed with preceding hyphens:

`:help -r` (cf. `:help r`)

Help for subtopics within the documentation for various Vim features usually has an appropriate hyphenated prefix:

`:help hl-Menu` (cf. `:help Menu`)
`:help syn-on` (cf. `:help on`)
`:help help-writing` (cf. `:help writing`)

Similarly, help topics within **plugins** generally use the plugin's name as a prefix:

`:help surround-mappings`

Finally, something I didn't realise until I'd been using Vim for a while* is that the help includes topics for the default mappings in all modes.

For example, `Ctrl-v` does something very different in Normal mode to what it does in Insert mode.

To get to the different topics, use the `i_`, `c_`, and `v_` prefixes for **Insert, Command, and Visual mode mappings**, respectively, or no prefix for the **Normal mode mapping**:

`:help ctrl-v`

`:help i_ctrl-v`

`:help c_ctrl-v`

`:help v_ctrl-v`

* <sub>...despite the fact that it's virtually the first thing you'll read if you type a plain `:help` with no arguments! See "Get specific help" a few paragraphs down. (`:help help-context`)</sub>

Comment: Most, though not all (specifically functions and plugins), of these are listed in `:help help-context`: Maybe that is worth mentioning in the answer as well.

Comment: @SakariCajanus Yes! `help-context` is actually almost the first thing on the front page of Vim's `:help`. I've added a footnote mentioning this to the answer.

Answer (score 4):

@Carpetsmoker's answer definitely satisfies the "most relevant" criteria, because the completions will almost always contain what you're looking for. However, there's also the [`:helpgrep`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/helphelp.html#:helpgrep) command, which works just like the `:grep` command but searches the text of all the help files.

You can browse through the results with `:cnext` or see all the results with `:cwindow`.