# How to search for documentation on an option which is also a vim command argument?

Tags: help-system

When a Vim option is also a Vim command argument, `:help` opens the command argument help page. How can I direct `:help` to get the option page?

For example, trying `:help verbose` opens the `-V verbose` command argument page, but I am looking for the in-editor `verbose` option documentation.

Note that when double-clicking on the `verbose` hyperlink in the command argument help, it opens the option help, but how to do it programmatically?

Trying these ended up with error:

```
:help &verbose
:help l:verbose
:help g:verbose
:help &l:verbose
:help &g:verbose
```

Comment: `:help 'verbose'` is what you want. It's a duplicate though, so I'll mark it as such.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2136/1841)

Comment: Thanks. I wonder why didn't this question come up in my search? By this time I found what I was looking for (see my answer below), but looks like it is only partially correct?

Comment: @ysap about the search duckduckgo wasn't good but searching `site:vi.stackexchange.com find option in help` on google returns the duplicate question, so a good advise is to use external search engine to find your answers rather than the in site search :) And I think the main issue with your answer is the confusion between "option" and "command"

Comment: Thanks. Apparently I was confusing the two, but interestingly, help opens the option's page rather than the command's page. Why is that?

Comment: OK, this is really confusing. Once I navigated to the command help page by clicking a hyperlink, now it actually opens the command's page rather than the option page. A Vim help bug?

Comment: @ysap Not sure what you mean... The link from `:help -V` goes to the `'verbose'` option. *"now it actually opens the command's page rather than the option page."* When does that happen? When you run which command or click on which link? On Vim's help system itself or on one of the online HTML copies of Vim help? Also try `Ctrl+]` on top of a link to follow it, that's the actual key-binding to follow a link (tag) in the help system, it might be more precise than clicking (I wouldn't be surprised if that was the case.)

Comment: I meant that when I wrote my answer, then `:he :verbose` opened the *option* help page (with tags `'verbose'`, `'vbs'`) rather than the *command* help page (with tags `:verb`, `:verbose`). Now it opens the correct help page.

Comment: Working as expected now. Go figure.

Comment: @statox Just for future reference, this is more clearly a duplicate than the one currently linked: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/438/shadowed-terms-in-help

Comment: Thanks Rich it is indeed closer to OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

So, searching for help on the `:help` command revealed the missing link. In order to get help on the option, one needs to search for the "tag" and add a `:` before the option name:

```
:help :verbose
```

Update: For the sake of future reference - this is incorrect, and the command should be:

```
:help 'verbose'
```

Comment: That's the "verbose" *command*, not the *option*... (options are the ones you update with the `:set` command.)

Comment: See my comment above.