# What is the difference between `tag` and `tags` command?

Tags: neovim, tags, ctags, navigation

I've recently come across the concept of tags in vim. I run ctags on a file and it generates tags for that file.

When I try to access those tags I use the `tag` command which basically provides a list of tags generated by ctags and it works just as I expect it to.

But there's also another command `tags` and I'm not sure what exactly does it do. I tried `h tags` but there wasn't a helpful documentation.

Can someone please point to any use cases of the `tags` command?

Comment: Does this account belong to the same person as the answerer? If so please let us know to merge them

Comment: For future reference, the documentation for the `:tags` *command* can be found at `:h :tags`. `h tags` is for the tags *feature*. See some more info on [disambiguating help topics in this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/2061/343).

Answer (score 0):

From `:help tag-stack`:

On the tag stack is remembered which tags you jumped to, and from where.
Tags are only pushed onto the stack when the 'tagstack' option is set.

The output of ":tags" looks like this:

```
   # TO tag      FROM line  in file/text
   1  1 main         1  harddisk2:text/vim/test
 > 2  2 FuncA       58  i = FuncA(10);
   3  1 FuncC          357  harddisk2:text/vim/src/amiga.c
```

This list shows the tags that you jumped to and the cursor position before
that jump.  The older tags are at the top, the newer at the bottom.

Comment: Does this account belong to the same person as the poster ? If so, please let us know to merge them

Comment: Yes it does. Do I have to merge them or will it be taken care of?

Comment: we’ll take steps on our end. (Never done this before, so I’m not 100% sure of the process. We’ll let you know though.)