What is :file in ex-mode?
It's not a command, it's not a builtin.
I don't know what it is; when I do :help file I get filename instead.
I want to know what it is because I want to pass a vimscript argument to it; but I try to, I get the name of the variable instead.
It works elsewhere in my vim config I think...

You might find this q&a helpful: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/438/343

Missing colon: :h :file

Learning to use its documentation is an integral part of learning Vim. Don't half-ass it.

Just to make sure the nail is hit riiight on its head…

What is :file in ex-mode?

Just ask Vim, but properly:
:help :file


It's not a command, it's not a builtin.

Yes, it definitely is a command, an Ex command to be more precise. I am not sure what you call "a builtin", though. Did you mean "builtin function"? "Builtin" is often used as an adjective in the documentation (and :file is definitely "builtin") but rarely if ever as a noun.

I don't know what it is; when I do :help file I get filename instead.

You are not asking the right question, so you are not getting the right answer. It is as simple as that.
You want to know what :file is so you ask Vim exactly that:
:help :file

and you get exactly what you need.

I want to know what it is because I want to pass a vimscript argument to it; but I try to, I get the name of the variable instead.

If you don't know what it is, then why do you want to pass "a vimscript argument" to it? Aren't you putting the carriage before the horses, here?
Furthermore, as an Ex command, :file is unable to accept an expression as argument. You will need to use :help :execute to concatenate the command and its argument:
:execute 'file ' .. whatever


It works elsewhere in my vim config I think...

One of the many cool things about Vim is that it is extensively documented with the best :help system of any text editor ever. It even comes with a brilliant, gently-paced tutorial that takes you from noob to efficient in a few weeks… if you are willing to put in some effort. My point is: everything is documented and accessible so there is literally no room for guesswork and assumptions and "I think…".
Slow down, take the time to go through :help user-manual up through :help usr_45, and you will get infinite reward for the rest of your career.

Also, see https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2136/how-do-i-navigate-to-topics-in-vims-documentation/2137#2137.

I did not know you could look up ex commands in help using the colon in the front.   When I did :help file I got something about built-ins.

In this case, there was nothing to "know" beforehand. You only had to ask your question properly. If you wanted info on :file, you should have asked about :file. But I insist: learn to use the doc.

Using :help :file gives
CTRL-G      or              *CTRL-G* *:f* *:fi* *:file*
:f[ile]         Prints the current file name (as typed, unless ":cd"
            was used), the cursor position (unless the 'ruler'
            option is set), and the file status (readonly,
            modified, read errors, new file).  See the 'shortmess'
            option about how to make this message shorter.

:f[ile]!        like |:file|, but don't truncate the name even when
            'shortmess' indicates this.


[snip]

                            *:file_f*
:f[ile][!] {name}   Sets the current file name to {name}.  The optional !
            avoids truncating the message, as with |:file|.
            If the buffer did have a name, that name becomes the
            |alternate-file| name.  An unlisted buffer is created
            to hold the old name.
                            *:0file*
:0f[ile][!]     Remove the name of the current buffer.  The optional !
            avoids truncating the message, as with |:file|.

